# Can I use my MacBook Pro as the screen for a mac mini

Tags: display, macbook-pro, mac-mini

I want to buy another Apple machine and instead of buying a whole new laptop, I am thinking of buying just a Mac mini and use my MacBook Pro screen as the screen for it. Is that possible ? What kind of connector would I need ? Would a simple USB cable do ? I am ready to buy a video connector for 30/40 bucks if that will do the job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer only uses the HD of the Mac Mini, while the processor and memory of the Macbook, which is not the definition of "Screen", but you'll be able to use the contents of the mini as use it as a boot disk.

1. Turn both machines off.
2. Boot the Mac mini into [target disk mode](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201462) by (a) holding the "t" key as the computer starts up, or (b) setting "Target Disk Mode..." in the "Startup Disk" system preference.
3. Connect a Thunderbolt or FireWire cable from Mac mini to MacBook Pro.
4. Boot the MacBook Pro, holding down alt/option key.
5. Choose the Mac mini hard drive when you get to the screen that shows the available disks. It should be the one with the FireWire icon (if you used that cable).
6. Voila, your MacBook Pro has booted from the external Mac mini, using it as its hard drive.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, if you're using simple apps like mail and browsing, [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) (Virtual Network Sharing) might do the trick without any hardware connections. It uses a network connection to stream your screen to a client.

For setting up your Mini as a server and your Macbook as a client, I recommend using this tutorial:

http://www.wikihow.com/Setup-VNC-on-Mac-OS-X

### Mac OS X 10.4 or 10.5 - Setup as Server

> Mac OS X 10.4 and 10.5 include the server component out of the box so all we need to do is turn it on.
>
> 1. Open your System Preferences from your blue apple menu.
> 2. Click the Sharing icon under the 'Internet and Network' category.
> 3. Highlight the Apple Remote Desktop component in the list of items.
> 4. Click Start to fire up Apple Remote Desktop service.
> 5. If you are NOT connecting with JollysFastVNC or ScreenSharing you need the following steps:
>
>    - Click Access Privileges to open the more advanced options.
>    - Check on VNC viewers may control screen with password and define a password.
> 6. You can close the System Preferences. You're done!

### Mac OS X 10.4 - Setup as Client

> To connect to your new VNC server from a remote machine you will need a VNC Viewer but luckily there are a number of free options out there.
>
> - The steps for setup will depend on the viewer you choose follow the documentation closely and you will have no problems creating a connection.
> - [JollysFastVNC](http://www.jinx.de/JollysFastVNC.html) is currently the fastest and actively developed VNC client including many features not available in any other client.
> - [Chicken of the VNC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cotvnc/) is an older client that is confirmed to work with this method simply connect using the IP address of the Server computer. (On the server use Safari or Firefox and goto www.whatismyip.com)

Comment: VNC is very slow with Macs, I've found.

Comment: I got an answer from Apple live chat. They say that MacBook Pro is not designed to take video as input.

Comment: @Randolph true, it's not ideal for multimedia. However I found that using it for simple web browsing and mail, it works fine.