# Can I use an iPad as the display for a Mac Mini?

Tags: mac, display, remote, ipad

Is it possible to use an iPad as the monitor for a Mac Mini? Input would be from the Mac Mini's keyboard and mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to set up the VNC server on the Mac (it's under System Preferences > Sharing > Screen Sharing), and use a VNC client on the iPad.

This goes over the network, not through a cable. It's possible there's an app and cable solution, but I haven't heard of one.

I just found [this post](https://superuser.com/q/235880/104286), which describes how to set up the Mini side of it.

Comment: If it's something over the air then it's going to update the ipad screen very slowly.

Comment: Depending on the connection, probably.  But it is a solution, and if you have a better one, please do post it.

Comment: I didn't mean it in a bad way just as a note.

Comment: Sorry if that sounded overly defensive, I tried but couldn't come up with a softer way to put it.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, there is [Air Display](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/air-display/id368158927?mt=8).

You can set it to mirror the desktop and it will act the same as a primary monitor for the Mac Mini. I'm not sure if this will be faster or slower than VNC, though.

Comment: Can I get an explanation for downvote? This is a perfectly viable solution given the criteria.